# How can I connect to IBM MQ using JNDI in c#?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, jndi, xms

I am currently able to connect to a IBM MQ using IBMXMSDotnetClient by specifying the connection properties directly in the c# code like below.

```
XMSFactoryFactory factory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
IConnectionFactory connFactory = factory.CreateConnectionFactory();
connFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "xxx");
connFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
connFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "xxx");
connFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
connFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "xxx");
```

But in Java, it seems that it can be done by JNDI bindings file.

From what I can see, it looks like that JNDI is something like TNS file (which specifies the connection details such host, port, SID, etc.) used by the client to connect to server in Oracle. **Is my understanding correct?**

If it is the case, **is it possible to connect to the IBM MQ by JNDI bindings files using IBMXMSDotnetClient?** All examples I can find is to set the connection properties (connFactory.SetXXXProperty) directly.

Comment: It is possible but you need to use JMSAdmin or MQ Explorer that comes with the java JMS client to create it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=applications-working-xms-net-administered-objects. You can also run sampleConsumer sample shipped with the product. There is an option to provide JNDI bindings file path for the sample

Comment: @JoshMc Sorry for the late reply. Would you mind putting more details, such as sample code? No need to be in great details, but just can give me an idea on how to do it.

Comment: @Shashi Sorry for the late reply. I cannot find the sample code in the URL provided. Also cannot find it at my local installation. Is there any direct link I can get the "sampleConsumer"  code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this snippet to create initial context and use it to create connection factory and sessions. Hope it will get you started.

```
        InitialContext ic = null;
        IConnectionFactory confac = null;
        IConnection conn = null;
        ISession sess = null;
        IMessageConsumer cons = null;
        IDestination dest = null;

        try
        {
            System.Collections.Hashtable env = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
            // Set the URL or PATH where the bindings file is located
            env[XMSC.IC_URL] = "file://c:/mqbindings/.bindings";
            // Initialize the context
            ic = new InitialContext(env);
            // Lookup for the connection factory name
            confac = (IConnectionFactory)ic.Lookup("myconfactoryname");
            // Create connection using the details from connection factory
            conn = (IConnection)confac.CreateConnection();
            // Create an auto ack session
            sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            // Lookup for the destination
            dest = (IDestination)ic.Lookup("myqueue");
            // ... rest of the code - create consumer or producer
        } 
        catch (XMSException xmsE)
        {
                // Handle exception
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got it working based on your sample code. All is ready, just missing a code sample.